# How to write a line graph on PPT using Apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

Is there a good example showing how to draw a line graph on PPT using apache POI?

I am using apache POIs XSLFSlide to generate PPT. I do not see one example to draw line using XSLFSlide.

Comment: "Is there a good example showing how to draw a line graph on PPT using apache POI?" Reads as if you want a line chart. "...example to draw line using XSLFSlide" Reads as if you want simply draw a line. So what is meant?

Answer (score 0):

In general this bar graph has the same concept. Just change to multi lines

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HSLFSlideShow ppt = new HSLFSlideShow();

    try {
        //bar chart data. The first value is the bar color, the second is the width
        Object[] def = new Object[]{
            Color.yellow, 40,
            Color.green, 60,
            Color.gray, 30,
            Color.red, 80,
        };

        HSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();

        HSLFGroupShape group = new HSLFGroupShape();
        //define position of the drawing in the slide
        Rectangle bounds = new java.awt.Rectangle(200, 100, 350, 300);
        group.setAnchor(bounds);
        group.setInteriorAnchor(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
        slide.addShape(group);
        Graphics2D graphics = new PPGraphics2D(group);

        //draw a simple bar graph
        int x = 10, y = 10;
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));
        for (int i = 0, idx = 1; i < def.length; i+=2, idx++) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.black);
            int width = ((Integer)def[i+1]).intValue();
            graphics.drawString("Q" + idx, x-5, y+10);
            graphics.drawString(width + "%", x + width+3, y + 10);
            graphics.setColor((Color)def[i]);
            graphics.fill(new Rectangle(x, y, width, 10));
            y += 15;
        }
        graphics.setColor(Color.black);
        graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        graphics.draw(group.getInteriorAnchor());
        graphics.drawString("Performance", x + 30, y + 10);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("hslf-graphics.ppt");
        ppt.write(out);
        out.close();
    } finally {
        ppt.close();
    }
}
```